# How do i get my API integration certified and published

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have an application to connect a work order / invoicing system to QB online API. A third party developed this and informed us that under developer licnece we only have 10 connections and we need to get certified and approved to have a proper integration licence.

How do we do that  ?

thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vendor licensing and product use. It should be addressed to the vendor; it is not a programming (code) related question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0040_publishing_your_app/submit_content_for_publishing for more details on publishing your application.

If you have questions, you can post them to https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/ instead of stackoverflow.